# What does this green/white icon in clan chat mean?

Tags: clash-of-clans

[image: That green thing]

Does this mean the player is online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually the icon representing the little menu that pops up when you tap a person's name.  It's the same color and shape as the menu, just really tiny.

It doesn't show up next to your own messages (the ones marked "You") and if you try tapping the word "You" you will see that you don't get the pop-up menu.

I can safely say that it has nothing to do with their online state - I see this icon next to every name in my clan chat, and I know for a fact that several of them are offline currently.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Thanks for clarifying. Still I wonder if there is/will be a way to check if a clan member is online, would be really helpful in terms of keeping the clan together. Thanks again